# How can I map TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to a Java data type using Hibernate 3.3.2GA?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, orm, sqldatatypes

How can I map Oracle column types [`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081) or [`TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006169) to a Java data type using [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) 3.3.2GA?  Can I map each of these to a [`Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) or [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) data type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). It has an [extension for hibernate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/index.html)

```
@Columns(columns={@Column(name="startTime"),@Column(name="startTimezone")})
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTimeTZ")
private DateTime startDateTime;
```

But first make sure you really need to store the time-zone. A better practice is to store times in a fixed TZ (say, UTC), and display them according to the current user preferences. People are interested in the time of an event in *their* timezone, and not in the timezone of the event source.

Comment: Doesn't `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` store in a fixed time zone (the database time zone) and translate the date to the client time zone?

Comment: I think you should avoid LOCAL. Make this in your application, rather than db configuration.

Comment: Bozho, I agree with your comment provided that all applications that access the database follow the same fixed time zone convention. In particular, all developers who may access the database directly through an adhoc query tool, for example, must be aware of the convention, otherwise, they could mistakenly interpret the event times in their own time zone instead of say, UTC.

Comment: Another reason to avoid a fixed time zone is if you may not change the JVM time zone (via `-Duser.timezone`) and there is a possibility that the JVM may move to a host located in a different time zone.  Then, the application will mix dates from two different time zones in the database.

Comment: Bozho, according to http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007248, developers should "Use the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE datatype when the application is used across time zones." Perhaps this is good advice when the developer does not have the right to change the time zone of the database and the JVM.

Comment: If times are coming from clients (desktop, javascript), without a server between the clients and the DB, then yes, using LOCAL is fine. Otherwise, the whether the application or the DB will be configured - it's the same.

Comment: Both the types serve the different purpose. LOCAL is good for storage of time information your application generates (timestamps in logs). Automatic time zone recalculation is great help when trying to display it to users. TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE on the other hand is great when you are integrating to other systems and you need to transfer information exactly as you get it, i.e. including original time zone. IMO best approach is to keep time handling to Oracle and Java should just blindly use it (no recalculations). But that is somehow hard to achieve. :-/

Comment: While it's correct that one may use PersistentDateTimeTZ to store the timezone in the database it must be noted that this is a database-agnostic solution as it requires an extra column for the timezone. It does NOT make use of the Oracle "timestamp with timezone" data type (>8i).

Comment: Its not always correct to say that 'People are interested in the time in their timezone'.   The time could be lots of things and saying that it should always be converted to local time is not always valid.